# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder is called too many times for one cell

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager. For each item in the grid, I need to call a REST api to retrieve data. Then, after get data asynchronously from remote,I use UIL to load/display image.

Everything seems to be fine. But i find onBindViewHolder is called **too too too many** times for specific items.

[logcat log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLtOU.jpg)

Talk is cheap, let me show you the code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    EditCourseImageAttachmentHolder holder = (EditCourseImageAttachmentHolder) viewHolder;
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams(position));
    holder.attachmentView.initData(dataSource.get(headerView == null ? position : position - 1), urlMap);
}
public static class EditCourseImageAttachmentHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final AttachmentView attachmentView;

    public EditCourseImageAttachmentHolder(AttachmentView itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.attachmentView = itemView;
    }
}
```

-----------AttachmentView.Java-----------------

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    subscription = tryLoadLocalImage(data)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> call(String localImageUrl) {
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(localImageUrl)) {
                        return Observable.just(localImageUrl);
                    }
                    if (urlMap.containsKey(data.getUid())) {
                        return Observable.just(urlMap.get(data.getUid()));
                    } else {
                        //Remote API call
                        String qiNiuUrl = getQiNiuUrl(data);
                        urlMap.put(data.getUid(), qiNiuUrl);
                        return Observable.just(qiNiuUrl);
                    }
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void call(String localImageUrl) {
                    showImage(localImageUrl);
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    if (subscription != null && subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root cause is I changed the LayoutParam of the ItemView....

It works well after i remove those code.
But, it's quite strange that only the item at specific position would re-bind.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

your code should be this...